# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext must be Retina-aware?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, core-image

I've read some posts which recommend the use of:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((image.size), NO, 0.0f)
```

instead of:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size).
```

Because the first one uses Retina-scale when drawing, otherwise you get blocky images.

I'm a little confused about when to use or not the retina-scale option.

If i have a photograph which is 1000x1000 px, and i call UIGraphicsBeginImageContext passing those dimensions, am i not specifying exactly how many points i want to draw? Is that ok?

Or should i call UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions passing half the dimensions (500x500px)? Does it make any difference?

Comment: `I've read some posts which recommend the use of... Because the first one uses Retina-scale when drawing, otherwise you get blocky images.` - this note helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can create the image context like this:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
```

Comment: According to the docs: _“If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.”_. Thus, using `0.0` there—instead of `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`—has the same effect, but will benefit from under-the-hood optimizations.

Comment: Thank you for this info, I see the docs say that scale = 0.0 equals the current screen scale, but cannot find anything about under the hood optimizations. Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 12):

You can get the scale value of your device by the following method

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]
```

With this information you can decide how many points you would like to draw.

Comment: I know, but what i'd like to now is if using: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(1000x1000px) is any different from using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((500x500px), NO, 0.0f).

Comment: isn't retina only important when showing the image, not drawing? i mean, i think it doesn't matter the size of the image, as long as when i'm showing it, i display it in a view with half the size (retina).

Comment: @jvic They both give you a 1000x1000px image. But I think the different is when using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(1000x1000px), the drawing are display on the screen is with 1000x1000 points, but UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((500x500px), NO, 0.0f) with 500x500 points, that's my guess.