# Converting UIView to UIImage gives poor quality

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiimage, resolution

I am using the following code to capture a UIView as a UIImage and save it in Docs Dir.

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

The UIImage is successfully saved. However the resolution is very poor. See the image below for reference. How do I make sure the resolution is retained as per the original image?[image]

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603212/uigraphicsbeginimagecontext-must-be-retina-aware

Comment: I got your point. But when i added it along with the previous code. Its not working. Can you suggest where shall I add it?

Comment: check my answer from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049796/howe-to-capture-uiview-top-uiview/14049828#14049862

Answer (score 0):

Capture the image of Entire view using below code :-

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
```

Comment: Sorry dude... This one doesnt seem to work :( The resolution is still wasted.